# expand the width to cover up the whole window

Tags: html, css

so i managed to get the width of the navbar to show from one side to the other with no spaces on the sides but that doesn't work for the footer and the content on the page, Even though my `.wrapper` class is containing all my visible content. I've tried to change the margin value for `.wrapper` to the same as the header but that did just work for one side, it just moved it to one side or the other. does anybody know why it works with the nav bar but not with the rest of the content?

```
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
border:1px solid red;}


#header {
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;}

<div class="wrapper">
<div id="header">


<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="scroll"></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="scroll"></a></li>    
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="scroll"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Film</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Foto</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>

 </div>

 <div id="project">
<h2>Project</h2></a>
</div>

<footer>
<div class="footlist">

<li>
<div class="ikon">
<a href="facebook"><img src="fb.png" alt="facebook" height="40" width="40"></a>
<a href="twitter"><img src="twi.png" alt="twitter" height="40" width="40"></a>
<a href="facebook"><img src="insta.png" alt="instagram" height="40" width="40">               
</div>
</li>

</div>


</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you add your html too

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i added the html, can you see whats the problem?